# Connect to Google Compute Engine instance to run Python script

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm very new to cloud computing and I don't come from a software engineering background, so excuse me if some things I say are incorrect.

I'm used to work on an IDE like Spyder and I'd like to keep it that way. Lately, in my organization we're experimenting with Google Cloud and what I'm trying to do is to run a simple script on the cloud instead of on my computer using Google Cloud's APIs.

Say I want to run this on the cloud through Spyder:

```
x=3
y=2
print(f'your result is {x+y}')
```

I'm guessing I could do something like:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
request = compute.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
request.execute()
#Do something to connect to instance


x=3
y=2
print(f'your result is {x+y}')
```

Is there any way to do this? Or tell python to run `script.py`? Thanks, and please tell me if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You needn't apologize; everyone is new to cloud computing at some point.

I encourage to read around on cloud computing to get more of a feel for what it is and how it compares with your current experience.

The code you included won't work as-is.

There are 2 modes of interaction with Compute Engine which is one of [several compute services](https://cloud.google.com/products/#compute) in Google Cloud Platform.

Fundamentally, interacting with Compute Engine instances is similar to how you'd interact with your laptop. To run the python program, you'd either start Python's REPL or create a script and then run the script through the python interpreter. This is also how this would work on a Compute Engine instance.

You can do this on Linux in a single line:

```sh
python -c "x=2; y=3; print(x+y)"
```

But, first, you have to tell Compute Engine to create you an instance. You may do this using Google Cloud Console (http://console.cloud.google.com), Google Cloud SDK aka "gcloud", or using e.g. Google's Python library for Compute Engine (this is what your code does). Regardless of which of these approaches you use, *all* of them ultimately make REST calls against Google Cloud to e.g. provision an instance:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
request = compute.instances().start(project=PROJECT, zone=ZONE, instance=INSTANCE)
request.execute()
#Do something to connect to instance
```

Your example ends `connect to instance` and this marks the transition between provisioning an instance and interacting with it. An alternative to your code above would be to use Google's command-line often called "gcloud", e.g.:

```sh
gcloud compute instances create ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE}
```

`gcloud` provides a convenience command that allows you to use `ssh` but it takes care of authentication for you:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--command='python -c "x=2; y=3; print(x+y)"'
```

**NB** This command ssh's into the Compute Engine instance and then runs your Python program.

This is not the best way to achieve this but I hope it shows you one way that you could achieve it.

As you learn about Google Cloud Platform, you'll learn that there are other compute services. These other compute services provide a higher-level of abstraction. Instead of provisioning a virtual machine, you can deploy code directly to e.g. a Python runtime. Google App Engine and Google Cloud Functions both provide a way by which you could deploy your program directly to a compute service without provisioning instances. Because these services operate at a higher-level, you may work from write, test and even deploy code from within an IDE too.

Google Cloud Platform provides a myriad of [compute services](https://cloud.google.com/products/#compute) depending on your requirements. These are accompanied by [storage services](https://cloud.google.com/products/#storage), [machine-learning](https://cloud.google.com/products/#ai-and-machine-learning), [analytics](https://cloud.google.com/products/#data-analytics), [internet-of-things](https://cloud.google.com/products/#internet-of-things), [developer tools](https://cloud.google.com/products/#developer-tools) etc. etc. It can be overwhelming but you should start with the basics (follow some "hello world" tutorials) and take it from there.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanaition, it was very enlightening! I'll keep studying to have a better grasp of cloud computing.

At least I managed to open a jupyter notebook hosted on my google compute engine instance and then connected it to my Cloud SQL database, so that's something.

I'll be looking into App Engine and Cloud Functions to see what else may I be able to do